# call function in program vs. in shell

Tags: python-3.x

Sorry if this question has been answered because it's kinda basic but yeah:

```
def fib2(n):
    a, b=0, 1
    fiblist=[]
    while a<n:
        fiblist.append(a)
        a, b=b, a+b
    return(fiblist)

fib2(100)
```

So this program is supposed to list some Fibonacci numbers, and so it does. The thing is that when i call the function inside the program above, the list still doesn't show when i run the program. The only thing that happens is that these two line appear:

```
>>> 
>>>
```

But if I just define the fib2(n) function without calling it on the last line and then calls it in the shell instead, the list is displayed in the shell

Why is that? Is it a difference between calling a function inside of a program versus calling it in the shell?

Answer (score 1):

The python interactive shell displays the values stored in the location pointed to by a variable when you just type that variable.

```
>>> a=10
>>> a
10
>>> b="string"
>>> b
'string'
>>> c="str\\ing"
>>> c
'str\\ing'
>>> print c
str\ing
```

When you run the interpreter on the program (python .py) this is not done. In order to see any value, you have to print it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... yo have to use the print functions, a programm is not an interactive shell

Comment: Hmm alright tankyou for the fast answer! Do you have any idea what you would need to do if you want the value of the function to be displayed? The value is shown if type print(fib2(n)) in the shell but not if I do it in the program.